# How to call one line of text from a php file to use in another?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use the title of an article in one place and be able to place it anywhere by calling it from the php file.

I tried to include the code from news.php and echo it in the footer, but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

news.php

```
<div class="entry-title">
    <h4>
        <a href="news/news-article-5-21-2019">
            <?php $str1 = "NEWS TITLE" ?></a>
    </h4>
</div>
```

---

footer.php

```
<div class="entry-title">
    <h4>
        <a href="news/news-article-5-21-2019">
            <?php include
            'news.php';
            echo $str1;
            ?></a>
    </h4>
</div>
```

I expected footer.php to output the "NEWS TITLE" from news.php, but didn't get anything.

Comment: If you view the raw page source (not the inspector view) in your browser what do you see? Is it the HTML markup with a missing value where the NEWS TITLE is expected, or nothing at all? When you get no output from PHP when output is otherwise expected, you need to check the web server's error logs for server errors. When developing and testing code, it helps to add at the very top of your PHP script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to force PHP to dump its errors to your screen.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I'm not seeing anything at all.

Comment: @AbraCadaver no, footer.php is not included anywhere in new.php. I'm trying to extract information from new.php to place into footer.php or any other file. Is there any way that I could do that?

Comment: Make sure that your PHP file news.php is included in the footer.php. Also, use inspect element on the footer to check for any warnings that you cannot see in the HTML made by PHP.

Comment: Although the news title in your example is hard-coded, presumably in real life it will be loaded from the database? Wouldn't it make more sense in your footer.php to make a database call to retrieve the same piece of data, and display it that way?

Comment: `<?php include 'news.php'; echo $str1; ?>` will include the entire file including all the HTML. You can include a php file (e.g. `strings.php`) with variables or constants set and then echo anywhere you wish.